# Mono project has hidden reference to assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

I have been working through a sample project I have downloaded. I have been tinkering with it trying to get it to compile and run on Mono. In order to do that, I have pulled all the references to `System.Data.Entity`. I have it to the point that it is compiling, but the minute I run it, I get an HTTP/500 stating that the Entity Assembly cannot be found:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.
Exception stack trace:
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I *know* I don't have that assembly. My solution is to pull all the references to it out. What locations could this reference be hiding in?

Comment: What kind of project is it? And what OS you use to run it? Have you tried to do fulltext search for "System.Data.Entity"?

Comment: Post it as an answer. I had done a full project search, not a full text search. It was included in a configuration file that was not included in the project, but was on the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do both a "full text" and a "full project" search for "System.Data.Entity" to find the location(s) of the remaining reference(s).

Comment: @Kavius, hopefully you can comment here on where you found the remaining reference using this method.